# Using find in OS X to identify then correct permissions

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, find

I'm trying to use find (or a better method, as this will then go into a shell script) to do the following:

- look at /Users directory
- identify any files or folders whose permissions are not 700, and if so, change them to 700, while ignoring the Sites and Public folders
- files and folders may have spaces in their names, too

This only needs to look one level deep, I.e. one level with a user's directory in /Users

This is what I've come up with so far but it doesn't quite do the trick:

```
find /Users ! -perm 0700 -type d -depth 2 | grep -v Public | grep -v Sites | /usr/bin/xargs -0 chmod 700
```

thanks for your suggestions!

Dan

Comment: Mmmm... your command only works for directories, not files which is different from what you asked for. Also, the net result of changing all things that are not "700" into "700" is that everything willl end up getting "700" so you might as well just change everything to "700" although this could have implications for backup and files looking like they have been changed. Also, you might look at the "-prune" option to exclude Public and Sites.

Comment: You're right, I'd probably need one find command for folders, and another for files, which isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
find /Users -maxdepth 2 \! -perm 0700 \! -name Public \! -name Sites -type d -exec chmod 700 {} +
```

No pipes, just one command `:)`

Note: I've changed your `-depth 2` to `-maxdepth 2` and moved it in front... just because GNU `find`'s `-depth` doesn't work like this and I believe this is how it would be written with GNU `find`. Now, I don't know about the `find` you have installed on your system, so YYMV, like they say...

I would also use `chmod`'s `-v` option, if available, just to know what's happening... something like:

```
`chmod -v 700 {}`
```

Experiment with the command I gave you like so:

```
find /Users -maxdepth 2 \! -perm 0700 \! -name Public \! -name Sites -type d -exec echo chmod 700 {} +
```

with the `echo` there, so that it's harmless. It will only print on your screen the commands that will be executed when the `echo` removed. Remove the `echo` only when you're happy with the way it behaves.

**Edit.** It seems that OS X and GNU versions of `find` differ in the use of `-depth`/`-maxdepth`. So here's a similar command for OS X (see [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1567509)'s [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746529/using-find-in-os-x-to-identify-then-correct-permissions/19747459#comment29345041_19747459)):

```
find /Users -depth 2 \! -perm 0700 \! -name Public \! -name Sites -type d -exec echo chmod 700 {} +
```

Cheers!

Comment: I think your suggestion may work best, though I had to change -maxdepth 2 to -depth 2 so that the parent folder wasn't chosen:         find /Users -depth 2 \! -perm 0700 \! -name Public \! -name Sites -type d -exec echo chmod 700 {} +

Comment: Am curious about making the same work for finding files lacking 700 perms, though the following yields an error I haven't seen (find: fts_read: Invalid argument) find /Users -depth 2 \! -perm 0700 -type f -exec echo chmod 700 {} +

Comment: @Dan I have no ideas, your command looks good! Have you tried with `find /Users -depth 2 \! -perm 700 -type f -exec echo chmod 700 {} +`? Btw, are you sure you want all files to be executable?

Comment: you're right about executable. Actually, I just need to make these directories and files unreadable by group and other so chmod g-rx,o-rx should do the trick, no?

Comment: @Dan with `chmod g-rx,o-rx`, group and others might still have write permission `:D`. So maybe `chmod go=` (i.e., `chmod 700`) so that they have no permissions at all. If you don't care about writable flag or want to preserve it, `chmod go-rx` is fine.